# sublimelinter-php for sublime 3 can not make it work

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I have tried several hours going through the documentation and trying to figure out how to make sublime linter-PHP work on my sublime console I get this message :

SublimeLinter: WARNING: php deactivated, cannot locate 'php' 
reloading Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings

can anyone help me out pls what needs to be done ?????